# Android: new information replace old information in notification

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

From the [documenation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification%29) of the `NotificationManager` in Android:

public void notify (int id, Notification notification) 
Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

```
it will be replaced by the updated information.
```

I don't want the old information to be replaced, I want both notifications.
NB: each notification has its own id:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

How to do this?

Comment: What is it you can't get to work? Its quite clear in your text...?

Comment: I want both notifications to be showed, I don't want the old one to be replaced by the update information.

Comment: Yeah then give it a new ID when you create it?

Comment: How can i give a new Id for a NotificationManager?

Comment: You wrote it in your question?

Comment: I also have similar question.

I am thinking whether it is good to do it by : notificationManager.notify((int)(Math.random()*1000000000), notification);

But is it a right way to do so? Or I simply let it be replaced? For example, two new messages becomes "you have 2 new messages, click to view".

Comment: Maybe I have found the answer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack your notifications

If your app creates a notification while another of the same type is still pending, avoid creating an altogether new notification object. Instead, stack the notification.

A stacked notification builds a summary description and allows the user to understand how many notifications of a particular kind are pending.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

public void notify (String tag, int id, Notification notification)

Since: API Level 5
Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same tag and id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Parameters
tag A string identifier for this notification. May be null.
id  An identifier for this notification. The pair (tag, id) must be unique within your application.
notification    A Notification object describing what to show the user. Must not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
private void notifyMe(String message) {
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        ncomp.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title));
        ncomp.setContentText(message);
        ncomp.setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_ticker));
        ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);      
        //nManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), ncomp.build());
        nManager.notify(int(System.currentTimemillisec
), ncomp.build());
    }
```